# Storage and show .txt files in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new at this. I have for example 50 different .txt files, where should I need to put them (in which folder) in android studio and how to display their titles in listview.

Comment: Well, you would put them in the `raw` directory, contained within `res`. However, are you sure that this is the best approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, to approach to .txt files from raw directory?

Comment: By placing them in `raw`, you can access them with `R.raw.yourTextFile`